# Why does u-substitution not work with this problem?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I tried to use u-substitution on the following integral, and I don't understand why it doesn't work.
$\int\arctan(2x)dx$

I let $u = 2x$, so $du = 2dx$. So $\int\arctan(2x)dx = \frac{1}{2}\int\arctan(u)du$. The antiderivative of arctan is $\frac{1}{x^2 + 1}$, so the integral becomes $\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{u^2 + 1} = \frac{1}{8x^2 + 2}$, but this isn't right. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Check again "the antiderivative of $\arctan$ is $\frac1{x^2+1}$"? (Also $+C$.)

Comment: No, you got it the wrong way round: the **derivative** of $\arctan{x}$ is $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. You need to use integration by parts.

Comment: Ohh, that was a dumb mistake. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You have calculated wrongly the integral.

Indeed, the derivative of $\operatorname{arctan}(u)$ equals the proposed expression.

In order to solve this integral, it can be done by IBP:
\begin{align*}
\int\arctan(2x)\mathrm{d}x = x\arctan(2x) - \int\frac{2x}{4x^{2} + 1}\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

In order to solve the second integral, it may be proceeded as follows:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{2x}{4x^{2} + 1}\mathrm{d}x & = \frac{1}{4}\int\frac{8x}{4x^{2} + 1}\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = \frac{1}{4}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}(4x^{2} +1)}{4x^{2} + 1}\\\\
& = \frac{\ln(4x^{2} + 1)}{4} + C
\end{align*}

Gathering the previous results, we achieve the desired expression:

\begin{align*}
\int\arctan(2x)\mathrm{d}x = x\arctan(2x) - \frac{\ln(4x^{2} + 1)}{4} + C
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!